# Is function call messing with other registers than %rax?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

This is gcc assembler code produced by my compiler. Comments describe what should be happenning (in my opinion), and i'm entering zero. Yet the output of the program is 4 (or 4 + whatever I put in the prompt).

```
.globl main
main:
    pushq %rbp 
    movq %rsp, %rbp 
    subq $0, %rsp 
    movq $1, %rbx           ; rbx = 1
    movq $46, %rdx          ; rbx = 1  rdx = 46 
    movq %rbx, %rcx         ; rbx = 1  rdx = 46  rcx = 1
    addq $7, %rcx           ; rbx = 1  rdx = 46  rcx = 8
    movq $4, %rbx           ; rbx = 4  rdx = 46  rcx = 8
    addq %rcx, %rbx         ; rbx = 12 rdx = 46  rcx = 8
    addq %rdx, %rcx         ; rbx = 12 rdx = 46  rcx = 54      
    callq read_int          ; rbx = 12 rdx = 46  rcx = 54      
    movq %rax, %rdx         ; rbx = 12 rdx = R  rcx = 54      
    negq %rbx               ; rbx = -12 rdx = R   rcx = 54      
    addq %rbx, %rcx         ; rbx = -12 rdx = R   rcx = 42      
    movq %rdx, %rbx         ; rbx = R  rdx = R   rcx = 42      
    addq %rcx, %rbx         ; rbx = R  rdx = R   rcx = 42 + R      
    movq %rbx, %rax         ; rax = 42 + R      
    movq %rax, %rdi
    callq print_int
    addq $0, %rsp
    movq $0, %rax
    popq %rbp
    retq
```

Don't really understand why this is the case. If I try compiling it without the read instruction it works fine. The only difference in code being

```
movq $0, %rdx
```

instead of

```
callq read_int
movq %rax, %rdx
```

But %rax register is not used before. And no register is holding 4. Code for read_int is

```
int64_t read_int() {
  int64_t i;
  scanf("%" SCNd64, &i);
  return i;
```

And it works fine by itself e.g. code that only only calls read int and moves rax into rdi, then prints it works fine.

Is this function call somehow messing with other registers?

Comment: yes. It's difficult to implement complex functions with only one register available, so other code does use other registers too. Check the calling convention for your target platform to see which registers are expected to be modified by other functions and which ones the other functions (and yours) should preserve. BTW from your question it's not clear what is your target platform, so hard to tell which calling convention is used by gcc.

Comment: Yes, rdx and rcx are both caller save registers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering:  rdx rcx are caller save registers. They need to be saved (e.g. on the stack) before calling the function

Comment: Caller-save is a misnomer; it's up the the caller whether it has anything it cares to save there or not. At the ABI level the dichotomy is between *call-saved* (which the caller can assume are preserved across a call; the callee must save/restore if it wants to use them) and *call-clobbered* (which the callee may freely use; the caller cannot assume anything about the values in these after a call).

Comment: @R..: I like "call-preserved" vs. "call-clobbered". Avoiding the word "saved" entirely avoids implying that actively saving/restoring is necessary in the caller or callee (In this case, save/restore some call-preserved regs around main so you can use them instead of RDX and RCX).  And yeah, the usual CS terminology "callee-saved" vs. "caller-saved" is terrible for multiple reasons.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, call-preserved is better terminology than call-saved. I'll try to adopt it.